# Split XML in multiple files

Tags: python, xml

I would like split XML to multiple XML files. I'm trying this script, but however, I keep getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\dokumenty\COVID-19\rozdel_export.py", line 4, in <module>
    for event, elem in context:
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1227, in iterator
    yield from pullparser.read_events()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1302, in read_events
    raise event
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1274, in feed
    self._parser.feed(data)
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 4, column 5
```

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

context = ET.iterparse('export.xml', events=('end', ))
for event, elem in context:
    if elem.tag == 'row':
        title = elem.find('ID').text
        filename = format(title + ".xml")
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n")
            f.write("<csv_data>\n")
            f.write(ET.tostring(elem))
            f.write("</csv_data>")
```

Comment: It looks like "export.xml" is broken on its line 4. Can you post a sample xml file we can check?

Comment: The problem is the XML file isn’t valid at line 4, column 5. Open the file in an editor and look at that line+column.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error, the issue is that your "export.xml" has an incorrect XML format.

`iterparse` has `recover` option, which tries hard to parse through broken input.

So you can try enabling this option and see if it works:

```
context = ET.iterparse('export.xml', events=('end', ), recover=True)
```

Please make sure that depending on the data in most cases you probably don't wish to ignore XML errors.

Comment: you're right, i repaired XML file and completed "f" to f.write(b"<... and now it's ok
thanks